# Searching strings from a file in another file for reaching values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file which has many columns and rows, and it looks like the example below:

```
file1.txt



    IDs     AABC  ABC6 YHG.8 D78Ha 
    Ellie   12      NA    48    33        
    Kate    98      34    21    76         
    Joe     22      53    49    NA                
    Van     77      NA    40    12
    Xavier  NA      NA    NA    88
```

So, if I cut the first column ( `cut -f1` ), it is :

```
IDs
Ellie
Kate
Joe
Van
Xavier
```

I have a second file (`file2.txt`) which has the some names in the IDs column, and sometimes the names does not exist in `file1.txt.`

```
file2.txt

Kate ABC6
Joe  YHG.8
Kate YGH.8
Sally D78Ha
```

What I am trying to do is, to read the `file2.txt`, and for each line, get the strings as keys ( kind of ) --> `Kate, ABC6` .

And then trying to find the value that this togetherness have in `file1.txt` , which is `**34**.`

And I want to write have the output as match and mismatch for all IDs. If `ID` ( either of the `Ellie,Kate,Joe,Van or Xavier`) with another column name exists in the `file2.txt` , then it is a `match`. If it does not. then it is a `mismatch`. And, I still want to print the value of this togetherness from the `file1.txt`.

```
output_for_line_1_in_file2.txt
    Ellie   ABC6  mismatch NA
    Kate    ABC6  match    34
    Joe     ABC6  mismatch 53  #mismatch because Joe ABC6 togetherness doesnt exist in file2.
    Van     ABC6  mismatch NA
    Xavier  ABC6  mismatch NA
```

And,

```
output_for_line_2_in_file_2.txt


     Ellie  YGH.8 mismatch 48
     Kate   YGH.8 match    21
     Joe    YGH.8 match    53  
     Van    YGH.8 mismatch 40
     Xavier YGH.8 mismatch NA
```

So `output_for_line3_in_file2.txt` will be the same as `output_for_line2_in_file2.txt` , as they share the same  second column name ( YGH.8 ).

I already got stuck in the finding the strings in `file2.txt` in `file1.txt` step:

```
import pandas as pd
tablefile = pd.read_csv('file1.txt',sep='\t')
print(tablefile)
df2=tablefile.set_index("IDs")
print("Ellie for AABC :" , df2.loc["Ellie", "AABC" ])

with open('file2.txt') as f:
    for wordtuple in (line.strip() for line in f):
        print wordtuple
        if wordtuple in df2:
            print(wordtuple, ',match')
        else:
            print(wordtuple, ',mismatch')
```

It prints :

```
    IDs  AABC  ABC6  YHG.8   D78Ha 
0   Ellie  12.0   NaN   48.0  33        
1    Kate  98.0  34.0   21.0  76         
2     Joe  22.0  53.0   49.0  NA               
3     Van  77.0   NaN   40.0  12
4  Xavier   NaN   NaN    NaN  88 
('Ellie for AABC :', 12.0)
Kate ABC6
('Kate ABC6', ',mismatch')
Joe AABC
('Joe AABC', ',mismatch')
Sally AABC
('Sally AABC', ',mismatch')
```

Which is already wrong as `Kate ABC6` should be a match, since it exists in `file2.txt`.
How can I get to these outputs?

Comment: I have already problems understanding the structure of file1. How does your program know, that value 48 in line Ellie belongs to column YHG.8 and not ABC6? A CSV reader would interpret your file like this.

Comment: True. I have to read it as a matrix. I am editing